# The most efficient way to assign values to a bunch of variables

Tags: c++, performance, variable-assignment

Suppose we have some integer variables, and all of them should get their values from a struct called "numberpool" via function call, and the value assignment should only be done by "entrykey":

```
struct numberpool{
    vector<int> numbers(100);
};

void assign(struct numberpool& src, int entrykey, int& dest){  // call by reference
    dest = src.numbers[tag];
    return ;
}

int main(){
    struct numberpool pool;  
    ...... // pool initialization

    int a, b, c, d, e .... z;   // 26 integers declaration

    // Assigning
    assign(pool, 1, a);
    assign(pool, 5, b);
    assign(pool, 23, c);

    ....and so on.

    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to know, is this the fastest way to complete this job? I doubt that there is more efficient way to do this, due to the frequently function calls.
What if I define another struct containing all the int variables, and just call a function once, would it help ?

Comment: Please comment on the use case. Why can't you just keep the vector?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong tags.

Comment: Because the vector life cycle is fleeting, so we have to keep some of its value.

Comment: In c++ `struct` is redundant when using with type, if you are not going to modify argument use const reference

Comment: Any reason why a,b,c ... aren't int references - because that would speed things up lots

Comment: @slava :thank you , I'll make it const.

Comment: `int a, b, c, d, e .... z;` can't you make this an array?

Comment: @UKMonkey: Like I said, the vector will change by the next cycle, so I have to use memory to keep the value, rather than a reference referring to it.

Comment: @drescherjm I'm afraid that the answer is no, because these variables are owned by different managers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an XY problem - perhaps you'd get better answers if you said your actually problem rather than your attempt to resolve it?

Comment: NO, this is not an XY problem. I presented the problem and my method, and I'm here to ask for the better one.
The real question is described above literally, HOW DO I SPEED THIS UP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the majority of your "tag" indices are grouped closely together, you can copy the underlying data as a single block:

```
struct subrange{
    static size_t min_ndx() constexpr { return 1; }
    static size_t max_ndx() constexpr { return 23; }
    static size_t storage_size() constexpr { return max_ndx() - min_ndx() + 1; }

    array<int, storage_size()> storage;
    int outlier_99; // Avoid copying indices between 24 and 99

    // accessors
    int &a() { return storage[1 - min_ndx()]; }
    int &b() { return storage[5 - min_ndx()]; }
    int &c() { return storage[23 - min_ndx()]; }
    int &d() { return outlier_99; }

    // Constructor allows numberpool to copy its vector
    subrange(const vector<int>& numbers)
        :storage(numbers.cbegin() + min_ndx(),
                 numbers.cbegin() + min_ndx() + storage_size()),
        outlier_99(numbers[99])
    {}
};

struct numberpool{
    vector<int> numbers(100);
    subrange copy_subrange( ) const {
        return subrange(numbers); };
    };

main()
{
    numberpool pool;  
    ...... // pool initialization

    // Copy a subset of memory, including data you're interested in,
    // and some chunks in between you're not.
    auto extracted = pool.copy_subrange();

    int sum = extracted.a() + extracted.b() + extracted.c() + extracted.d();
```

Copying a block of memory may or may not be faster, depending on your exact situation.  When in doubt, try both ways.

Comment: Copying a block of memory may or may not be faster, many thanks, I'll remember that

Answer (score 2):

The performance of the function calls is not your problem here. The compiler will be able to optimize it quite well.

However, seeing so many variables makes me cringe. Unless you really have a meaning behind each and every of the variables (apart from being letters of the alphabet), you should think about another design. If you really want to map the alphabet to numbers, you should just use an array.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, sir.

Answer (score 2):

Use method instead of standalone function and assign natural way:

```
struct numberpool{
    vector<int> numbers(100);
    int get( size_t tag ) const { return numbers[tag] };
};

int main(){
    numberpool pool;  
    ...... // pool initialization

    int a = pool.get(1);
    int b = pool.get(5);

    ....and so on.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank both of you, same question here, does it really enhance my method ?

Comment: @koalo because it shows intent cleaner way and and makes it easier to process for optimizer.

Comment: @koalo because you may want to change implementation details and keep public interface intact. Though `numbers` should be private, but that is a different story.

Comment: @koalo Because in real situation, numberpool is a structure more than just a vector in it, it should be accessed by entry, but I just simplied it into vector.

Comment: @Shih-ChanHuang So in contrast to your statement above, you have some side constraints. So you should specify them in the question!

Comment: @koalo sorry about my fault :'(